# Interrupt all running signals in Python?

Tags: python, signals

How can I interrupt all running signals in a Python script? I would like something like `signal.interrupt_all()`.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean? Do you want to temporairly ignore a signal, or to completely ignore some kinds of signals?

Generally speaking, you can't "vanish" a signal once it has been generated. You either set its action to "ignore" or you block the signal, preventing it from being delivered, but you need to do this *beforehand*.

On POSIX systems, your options are (see [Signal Concepts](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)):

- **Ignore** the signal by setting its handler to `SIG_IGN`. This will also cause pending signals to be ignored (see [Signal Concepts: SIG_IGN](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_02)).
- **Block** a signal from delivery. The signal will remain pending but your process/thread won't receive it (until it is unblocked). Unfortunately, you can't block signals in Python: see the [signal module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html).

Note that you can't interrupt a signal handler (signal-catching function); this shouldn't be a problem, as signal handlers are expected to return quickly.

See also this question: [Trapping Signals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654215/trapping-signals-in-python).